# FullCalendar: How to sort & display Events on Day of MonthView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

All events on day slot of monthly view are sorted based on the start time i.e. event start hour 0-23, hour 0 on top and 23 on bottom.

But I want to show the active(`event.IsActive == true`) tasks on top and after the Active task list, inactive(`event.IsActive == false`) tasks will be displayed sorted by start hour 0-23.

Example:

1. ActiveTask-1      12:00AM
2. ActiveTask-2      3:00AM
3. ActiveTask-3      21:45PM
4. InactiveTask-1    12:00AM
5. InactiveTask-2    7:00AM
6. InactiveTask-3    23:30PM

Is this possible in fullCalendar?

Comment: What do you mean by IsActive? I skimmed the docs and there seems to be no definition for this.

Comment: I have added few custom properties to the events. IsActive is a boolean property.

Comment: Figured as much >.>. But what I meant was, when are you setting it and how.

Comment: I am adding custom properties from EventSource. Lets think about this >> Events with ((event.id % 2) == 0) would be on top and ((event.id % 2) == 1) would be on bottom sorted by time. Is this doable? if yes, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried Jquery week calender http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html

Answer (score 9):

Your request will need to directly patch the fullcalendar code.
This is mandatory because fullcalendar doesn't expose this function to the outside world.

I did check my response with version 1.4.11, but looking at the 1.5 branch on github shows that it should be the same.

The function to be patched is `segCmp`, (found in `src/util.js`for the source version, or simply near the end of the file in fullcalendar.js)

The original version is:

```
function segCmp(a, b) {
  return (b.msLength - a.msLength) * 100 + (a.event.start - b.event.start);
}
```

The patched version should look like that:

```
function segCmp(a, b) {
  var activeDiff = ((b.event.IsActive || false) - (a.event.IsActive || false));
  if (activeDiff != 0) return activeDiff;
  return (b.msLength - a.msLength) * 100 + (a.event.start - b.event.start);
}
```

I simply check wether the events have a different IsActive state and return the diff, if no diff the previous algorithm is preserved. (Note the b - a diff because you want IsActive:true BEFORE IsActive:false)

Note that `segCmp` is called when splitting/ordering events and thus will apply in all views.

Best Regards,

Pascal

Answer (score 3):

when this feature is implemented, it would solve your problem:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=364

Comment: Is this being implemented in V2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely override the sorting by start date for allDaySlot, month, basics views.
For example to sort them by color.

1.Initialise [eventOrder](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventOrder/) to color. (html/php file you are using)

```
eventOrder: 'color,start'
```

2.Change the compareSegs function. (fullcalendar.js)

```
// original function
compareSegs: function(seg1, seg2) {
    return seg1.eventStartMS - seg2.eventStartMS || // earlier events go first
        seg2.eventDurationMS - seg1.eventDurationMS || // tie? longer events go first
        seg2.event.allDay - seg1.event.allDay || // tie? put all-day events first (booleans cast to 0/1)
        compareByFieldSpecs(seg1.event, seg2.event, this.view.eventOrderSpecs);
}

// custom function
compareSegs: function(seg1, seg2) {
    if(this.view.name=="basicWeek"){ // ordering events by color in ListView
    return seg2.event.allDay - seg1.event.allDay || // tie? put all-day events first (booleans cast to 0/1)
        compareByFieldSpecs(seg1.event, seg2.event, this.view.eventOrderSpecs);
    }
    else{
        return seg1.eventStartMS - seg2.eventStartMS || // earlier events go first
                    seg2.eventDurationMS - seg1.eventDurationMS || // tie? longer events go first
                    seg2.event.allDay - seg1.event.allDay || // tie? put all-day events first (booleans cast to 0/1)
                    compareByFieldSpecs(seg1.event, seg2.event, this.view.eventOrderSpecs);
    }
}
```

In this case I only want to sort event by color in the "basicVeek" view.
Then I have remove the eventStartMS & eventDurationMS tests.

REMOVE:

```
seg1.eventStartMS - seg2.eventStartMS || // earlier events go first
seg2.eventDurationMS - seg1.eventDurationMS || // tie? longer events go first
```

Comment: can you describe something here instead of giving link?

Comment: Edit made, i removed the link then i copy/past my post