# Render event on top fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

We are using the jquery plugin fullCalendar for a project at work. However, we want to display certain events with certain properties on top in each day column. The problem is that I don't want to change the source code of Fullcalendar.js if I don't have to and it even seems that it's using the minified .js for rendering events.

I know that it exists a trigger that triggers an custom event `eventRender: function (event, element)` but I'm out on ideas to render the event at top. For this example we might say that event got an `important` attribute.

So I guess this psuedo-code will make my example more clear:

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    if(event.important) {
        //render at top
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you want to reorder your events (for a particular day) based on importance, right? Also, do your events have time on them or just date?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with fullcalendar. You would have to manipulate the js and create an importance row such as the allDay row in the table.

Comment: That's right ganeshk. I am prepared to edit the js and create an importance row. But I don't really know where to start editing. The code is kind of messy.

But I guess I'll have to try.

Comment: This relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525126/fullcalendar-how-to-sort-display-events-on-day-of-monthview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement for my task changed in such a way that now every event has a special priority which is an integer. The higher the number, the more importance it got.

Old:

```
// Old function, this won't sort based on importance first!
function segCmp(a, b) {
    return (b.msLength - a.msLength) * 100 + (a.event.start - b.event.start);
}
```

New:

```
function segCmp(a, b) {
    var priorityDiff = ((a.event.priority || 0) < (b.event.priority || 0)) ? 1 : ((b.event.priority || 0) < (a.event.priority || 0)) ? -1 : 0;
    if(priorityDiff != 0) return priorityDiff;
    return (b.msLength - a.msLength) * 100 + (a.event.start - b.event.start);
}
```

For you who want to use this, your event JSON have too look something like this:

```
{
allDay: false,
color: "#7BD148",
id: "1",
key: "1",
start: "2013-01-28 13:07:00",
title: "test event",
url: "http://google.se",
priority: 10
},
{
allDay: false,
color: "#7BD148",
id: "2",
key: "2",
start: "2013-01-28 12:07:00",
title: "test event 2",
url: "http://google.se",
priority: 5
},
```

As you may see the second event is scheduled earlier but with the added code it will order the two by their priority. So the first event will go first, with the second event following it.

That's how I solved it, priority is an integer and I am trying to sort by that except if they are the same or if they doesn't exist (null / undefined). Its sorting by the highest integer.

That function is in fullCalendar.js.

Comment: This is a useful feature. You should open a request [issues](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/list) to have FC expose that function as a callback..

Comment: I actually made a pull request to FC-repo on github yesterday. But I couldn't find any issue there. But I guess they have it on google code. Thanks, will do.

Comment: @cubsink how can we stack all the events whose end time is greater than the start time of next event at the top? For example if event is starting from previous date than it should be on the top. Your help will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: I think you can take the old function: `return (b.msLength - a.msLength) * 100 + (a.event.start - b.event.start);` and multiply it with -1, (altough I haven't tested it). Like this: `return parseInt((b.msLength - a.msLength) * 100 + (a.event.start - b.event.start)) * -1;`. Tell me if it works!

Answer (score 1):

FullCalendar has added this feature starting v.2.4.0. It is called "[eventOrder](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventOrder/)", and is a setting of calendar options. You can pass in the name of the property of your events as argument, and it will sort events alphabetically according to that property.

```
// start calendar
var $calendar = $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    // Start of calendar settings
    header: {
        left: 'title',
        right: 'today,month,agendaDay,agendaWeek prev,next'
    },

    // setting to display sorted based on this property
    eventOrder: "priority",

    events: data
}
```

And for example, data is:

```
data = [
    {
        title: "event1",
        start: "2017-01-25"
        priority: "a"
    },
    {
        title: "event2",
        start: "2017-01-26"
        priority: "b"
    },
    {
        title: "event3",
        start: "2017-01-27"
        priority: "c"
    }
]
```