# fullcalendar event sorting not working for me

Tags: javascript, sorting, fullcalendar

Using [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) v3.8.2. I'm struggling with getting my events to sort. I've read (and re-read) the stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252552/change-default-event-sort-order-on-fullcalendar-month-view). I'm using the [evenOrder](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOrder) and have tried various options but always getting results like screenshot below. These are "all day" events. This is a boat launch calendar and I always want to show "put ins" before "take outs".

Cleary the events are not ordered by title, nor are they ordered by any of the `eventOrder` options that I've tried.

[image: screen shot]

Currently my code looks like:

```
  $calendar.fullCalendar({
    eventOrder: function(e) {
      return e.miscProps.sort;
    },
```

With data that looks like:

```
{start: "2019-01-02", title: "30 put ins", className: "putin", sort: "0"}
{start: "2019-01-16", title: "1 take outs", className: "takeout", sort: "1"}
```

A "putin" event is always a `sort:0` and a "takout" is always `sort:1` The `eventOrder: function()` is being called and correctly returning either 0 or 1.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you supply a function for `eventOrder` then, as the [eventOrder docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOrder) you linked to state, it accepts *two* input parameters (the two events which need to be compared and sorted), and you are also told that it's supposed to return either `-1`, `0` or `1` as the result of the comparison - as an indication of which of the two input items should be placed first.

If the first event should be first in the list, then return -1. If the opposite, then return 1, if they're equal then return 0. The logic within it should be very similar to the sample code provided in the docs for the native JS array sort function - see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description

Your logic currently will just return the "sort" value for whichever event happens to be first in the un-sorted list. This is not doing any kind of comparison at all, and it also doesn't supply the full range of possible values the calling code expects (i.e. you only ever return 0 or 1, never -1 - but even if you did it wouldn't necessarily make sense).

A working comparison function would be:

```
eventOrder: function(a, b) {
  var result = 0;
  if (a.miscProps.sort < b.miscProps.sort) result = -1; //event a should be listed first
  else if (a.miscProps.sort > b.miscProps.sort) result = 1; //event b should be listed first
  return result;
},
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c9upo8w2/1/

But...actually you don't need to write a custom function for this as far as I can see, because you're ordering very straightforwardly on the ascending sequence of numbers in the "sort" field alone. There's no complex calculation to be done. Specifying the field on which to sort will do the job perfectly nicely - fullCalendar will do the rest. Again the documentation you linked you states that if you supply the name of a field as the "eventOrder" option then it will sort (otherwise equal) events in ascending order by that field. So:

```
eventOrder: "sort"
```

is the only thing you need to write.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c9upo8w2/

---

P.S. Just as an aside, the sample data you've given above isn't much use because they're on different days anyway, so the custom sort won't apply. Obviously in this case I was easily able to change it in order to create the demos, but it would make more sense to supply an example which actually reproduces the issue :-)

Comment: Thank you for the detail explanation. I should have read the documentation regarding the use of the function more thoroughly. I'd started playing with the function after other attempts failed, specifically using eventOrder: 'className' which would eliminate my need for "sort". But className is an array, so I started using the function, still no joy (since I hadn't digested the documentation) so I went brute force and added "sort", at which point I guess I had myself pretty well confused. Any elegant way to use className w/o a function?

Comment: In your data sample, the className field seems to be a string rather than an array. So if you tell it to sort by this field it will do a simple alphabetical sort, which may not be what you want. If you need to look at the values and place them in order based on some other interpretation of the className value then you'll need a custom function.

Comment: I appreciate your help and do not want to waste more of your time. Simply using eventOrder: 'className' does not produce alphabetical sorting. Within  eventOrder:function(a,b), "className" is a property of "a" and "b", and it is there that is is an array. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah ok. The className property from your original data would be within "miscProps" just like "sort" is. The other property perhaps refers to the CSS classes assigned to the event, I would guess (not at a computer to test it right now)

Comment: Right. 'className' is the CSS class assigned to the event. It shows up as an array on the event, not in 'miscProps'. And doesn't seem to work as an eventOrder: value, which is where I started. I was trying to overload it for both style & sorting. But I have learned a lot along the way thanks to your patient assistance.

Comment: I see. We'll either way, if it's an array you would definitely need a custom function to deal with it, because it's not possible to make a simple comparison between an array on event a and an array in event b and say which one is "first" or "last". You'd need some extra code to look inside the array and make the decision based on some facet of the contents. The default sorting code can't do that, because it won't know what specifically within the particular array you're expecting in that property is going to be important. Does that make sense?

Comment: Totally makes sense. I learned a lot that I would not have without your help.