# How can we drag and drop a title block with in same day in full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to swap between two titles on the same day in fullcalendar.
How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Basically you need to sort events. Please try to use eventOrder as mentioned in Docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOrder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054852/fullcalendar-event-sorting-not-working-for-me

Comment: What would it achieve to drag them within the same day? You can't change the time by doing (at least, not in the month view you can't, anyway, because it has no concept of times, only days). The events are displayed in a sensible, meaningful order, as defined here: fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOrder). If you can drag them about without changing the time or day, it just makes the ordering inconsistent and confusing. As Khurram says, you _could_ change the general ordering rules by changing the eventOrder setting, so every day's events are ordered differently - but, importantly, still consistently.