# jQuery Fullcalendar, how to order event sources?

Tags: fullcalendar

i am using jQuery [Fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io), i am using two event sources (one is from google calendar, the other is internal list), problem is that they are mixed inside the day cell of the month.
I would like to show google calendar events first.
Is this possible to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Hey read this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525126/fullcalendar-how-to-sort-display-events-on-day-of-monthview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231902/jquery-fullcalendar-event-sorting and the doc: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventOrder/:) i hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks but those solutions are for ordering events based on their time, i am looking solution about ordering event sources.
Anyway, those are interesting threads where learning more about Fullcalendar.